# deleted file won't go away

Tags: tfs

I'm somewhat new to tfs and am trying to learn it.  I've been trying to do as much as I can from the command line (tf and tfpt).  My current dilemma is that I "got" a previous version (changeset) of the source code.  Now I've updated to the latest version and a certain file is now deleted.  However it is still there in my local workspace.  What is the correct way to get rid of it?  Why is it still there?
Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `tfpt.exe scorch`